# OpenStack API V2 tenants returns only one tenant

Tags: api, authentication, openstack

I'm tring to fetch the list of tenants using the identity (Keystone) API, V2, of OpenStack.

After I authenticate as user "admin" on the public port (5000). 
I am able to make a /v2.0/tenants call to the identity API, also on port 5000,  using the token I got from the authentication. However, it only returns a single result, while there are multiple tenants.

I tried many things to overcome this:

- Used port 35357 - the /tenants call returned 401 unauthorized
- Tried port 7777 with the admin token - got 401

  - The same call from the PostMan Chrome extension did work
- tried to repeat the suggestion [in this thread](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/160/openstack-apis-and-admin-user/?answer=236#post-id-236) - my authentication call with tenant name failed on request format, and I couldn't find any example to how such a request should look

Some observations:

- I added user "admin" as admin in multiple projects
- The authentication response:

  - shows no roles for user admin
  - metadata shows is_admin=0
  - serviceCatalog appears empty

Any help will be appreciated

Yaron

Answer (score 1):

The /tenants API returns the list of tenants that your user has access to. The admin user does not automatically have access to all tenants - it has permission to assign users to any tenant, though. So check again if your user actually has permissions to all of these tenants.

If you have access to the Openstack Horizon dashboard, login with your user and see the list of tenants that you can choose (usually available as a select-box in the top-left of the screen - depends on your openstack distro)

I recommend that you use the Openstack CLI with the --debug option - use the cli to list the tenants you have access to. The debug flag will output the Openstack API calls to the console screen.

Comment: Hi Barak,

Thanks for the answer. As I said, I did add user "admin" as admin in multiple projects.
When I used CLI with debug output on the controller host, it does return the full list, but I noted that after it authenticates to port 5000, it does the tenants call to port 35357. When I tried to replicate this behavior, I got a 401 return code.

Comment: I guess I left one crucial detail out: I need to make the API call from another host. Looking at the endpoints list I get from the "keystone endpoint-list" I see that the admin URL for identity service is only accessible from 192.168.0.2:35357. I wonder if that explains why I'm not getting administrator privileges and always get a single tenant in the /tenants response.